# Where are things like zval defined?

Tags: c, eclipse, eclipse-cdt, php-extension

I'm trying to develop a PHP extension using Eclipse and CDT, but the extension code is reported as full of syntax errors and warnings. I managed to get rid of part of them by telling CDT to look for the PHP `include` directory and the `main` directory from the PHP source code, which resolved all the includes, but there are still a lot of problems.

Specifically, where do I find the definition for `zval`, `SUCCESS`, `FAILURE`, `STANDARD_MODULE_PROPERTIES`, `zend_module_entry`, `zend_function_entry` and `zend_parse_parameters`? How do I get CDT to not mark `<module name>`, `<module name>_functions` and `return_value` as an unresolvable symbols?

Is there a better way to develop a PHP extension using an IDE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For where to find:

```
typedef struct _zval_struct zval;                     : ./Zend/zend.h
struct _zval_struct {                                 : ./Zend/zend.h
SUCCESS                                               : ./Zend/zend.h
FAILURE                                               : ./Zend/zend.h
STANDARD_MODULE_PROPERTIES                            : ./Zend/zend_modules.h
typedef struct _zend_module_entry zend_module_entry;  : ./Zend/zend_modules.h
struct _zend_module_entry { :                         : ./Zend/zend_modules.h
typedef struct _zend_function_entry {
…
} zend_function_entry;                                : ./Zend/zend_API.h
zend_parse_parameters(                                : ./Zend/zend_API.c
```

If you want to look at PHP source code like that i suggest you use i.e. Vim in combination with `cscope`. Then all you have to do is have the marker on i.e. `zval`, enter two keys and it jumps to the definition.

---

From a quick google it looks like Eclipse also has some cscope support or the like. `Search workspace`? It would require you to load the PHP source in to workspace tho I guess.

When it comes to CDT I have no idea. Never used it.

---

Edit:

Had a look at it out of curiosity and need to get to know CDT.

- Created a standard C project.
- Right click project

  - Paths and Symbols

    - Source location; added PHP directory.
- Right click project

  - Index

    - Rebuild (Big source so takes a while)

Now I can say i.e. `zend_parse_param` <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> and get auto completion. Or `zend_parse_parameters(` <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>.

Or select `Search` -> `C/C++...` and select i.e. "Definitions", text "zval" -> search and get definitions.

Or type `zva` <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> and get `zval` etc.

You can also right click PHP source in `Project Explorer` and select i.e. `Exclude from build` etc.